# difficulties at dealing with scheme interpreter

Tags: scheme, racket

I have written this code on paper, and as far as I know it's totally correct, but once I run it in Dr. Scheme, I get an error. I think it has something to do to deal with the interpreter. What is wrong with this code?

```
#lang scheme
(define (compare x y)
  (cond
    ((> x y) (display '(x is greater than y)))
    ((< x y) (display '(y is greater than x)))
    (else (display '(x and y are equal)))))
```

Comment: Works fine for me. What error message are you seeing?

Comment: @uselpa if you apply 2 3 for example it will print them back it will not compare them

Comment: `(compare 2 3)` yields `(y is greater than x)`, which is correct. What output do you expect?

Comment: so you need to write (compare 2 3) not only 2 3 . Thanks so much bro > I hope you write it as answer so I can mark it as solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For output, I'd suggest you use `printf`:

```
(define (compare x y)
  (cond
    ((> x y) (printf "~a is greater than ~a\n" x y))
    ((< x y) (printf "~a is greater than ~a\n" y x))
    (else    (printf "~a and ~a are equal\n" x y))))
```

so that

```
(compare 2 3)
=> 3 is greater than 2

(compare 3 2)
=> 3 is greater than 2

(compare 3 3)
=> 3 and 3 are equal
```

Also, try to use DrRackets *reindent all* feature, and avoid closing parenthesis on their own line.